# When ever I want to install npm install java so i got the list of error?

Tags: python, java, node.js, windows, npm

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Portals\SALAM_DMS\finger\node-java\node_modules\java
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is  :\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:330:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:159:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:228:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:294:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\Portals\SALAM_DMS\finger\node-java\node_modules\java
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\arbab\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-31T12_39_25_371Z-debug.log
```

Comment: This is due to the missing python3 command in your computer, you must first install python 3 and then add PYTHONPATH to the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

open cmd run as administrator

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools
```

it will download the python related dependencies.
then run

```
npm install
```

then

```
ng serve
```